# If $f,g:U \longrightarrow R $ be twice differentiable function, $f(a)= g(a)$, $df(a)=dg(a)$ and $d^2f(x)=d^2g(x)$, then $f=g$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f,g:U \longrightarrow R $ be twice differentiable function and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and $U$ a convex open set, such that $f(a)= g(a)$, $df(a)=dg(a)$ and $d^2f(x)=d^2g(x)$ for all $x \in U$, then $f=g$.

Note:
if $v=\left(\alpha_1,\dots ,\alpha_n \right) $ then
$d^2f(a) v = \Sigma_{i,j}\frac{\partial{f} }{{\partial x_i}\partial x_j}\left( a\right) \alpha_i \alpha_j $

My approach:

For Taylor

$f(a+u)= f(a)+df(a)+r(u)$

$g(a+u)= g(a)+dg(a)+h(u)$

where

$\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{r(u)}{|u|}=\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{h(u)}{|u|}=0$

Now I use Lagrange Remainder: $U$ is a convex set, then $\left[a, a+v \right] \subset U $, $f,g \in C^1$ and are twice differentiable function in $\left(a,a+u \right) $, then there are $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in \left( 0,1\right)  $    such that

$r(u)= \frac{1}{2}d^2f(a+\theta_1 u)u^2= \frac{1}{2}d^2g(a+\theta_1 u)u^2$

$h(u)= \frac{1}{2}d^2g(a+\theta_2 u)u^2$

anyone have a tip to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to prove the following claim:

$$d^2 h(x)\equiv0\quad\Rightarrow\quad h(x)=p\cdot x+ q\tag{1}$$
with constant vectors  $p$ and $q$. When $(1)$ is established we can apply it to $f-g$ in your question. When $df(a)=dg(a)$ then $p=0$, and when also $f(a)=g(a)$ then $q=0$.

In order to prove $(1)$ we argue coordinatewise. Choose a $j\in[n]$, and let
$$\psi(x)=\bigl(\nabla h(x)\bigr)_j={\partial h\over\partial x_j}\ .$$
We then have
$$\nabla\psi(x)=\left({\partial^2 h\over\partial x_j\partial x_1},\ldots,{\partial^2 h\over\partial x_j\partial x_n}\right)\equiv0\ .$$
It follows that $x\mapsto\psi(x)$ is a constant $p_j$ , and this implies $\nabla h(x)\equiv p$ for a constant vector $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$. A second such step then proves that $h(x)=p\cdot x+q$, since $h(x)-p\cdot x$ has zero derivative.